# Overloading a parent member function without ref-qualifier with a child member function with ref-qualifier in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, ref-qualifier, function-qualifier

In C++ one cannot overload in one class a member function with ref-qualifier with a member function without ref-qualifier. But at the same time it is possible to inherit one member function from a parent class and overload it in a child class as in the example:

```
struct A {
    void f() {}
    //void f() & {} //overload error everywhere
};

struct B : A {
    using A::f;
    void f() & {} //ok everywhere
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.f(); //ok in GCC only
}
```

Only during the invocation of `f`, Clang complains that `call to member function 'f' is ambiguous`. But GCC accepts the program without any error, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5zzbWcs97

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Huuuh, curious. It looks like they use different versions of standard for this.

Comment: I would say gcc-bug. (msvc rejects it as clang [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jb8eqrdnY)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC is **correct** to accept this, but the situation changed recently.  The current phrasing is that a *using-declaration* in a class ignores (base-class) declarations that would be ambiguous (in a sense that is more strict than for overload resolution, partly because there is no argument list yet) with other declarations in the class.  `void()` and `void() &` members are ambiguous in this sense, so `b.f` finds only `B`’s `f` and the call is valid.

In previous (as of this writing, that means “published”) versions of the standard, both functions would be made available because the `&` distinguished them (in a sense that is even stricter), which would not only render the call ambiguous (as Clang says) but be ill-formed outright because the base- and derived-class functions were checked for **overload** compatibility which they lack.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add a link to this point in the standard?

Comment: @Fedor http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#11

Comment: So, which compiler is actually wrong here in the end? I'd like to report this bug to one of them, so that they act the same

Comment: @dragonroot: GCC is correct.  The committee doesn’t usually issue the Technical Corrigenda needed to formally make this true for C++20, but I’d expect it to be (eventually) implemented for all language modes back to C++11.  Clang isn’t right in any language version because it rejects only the call.

Comment: Thanks, reported here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55907