# Which c++ compiler is wrong on this code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, using

The following is compiled fine by gcc (12.1 and trunk), but clang (14.0.0 and trunk) gives an error on `d.foo()`, saying the call is ambiguous. Question is, to which compiler should I report a bug?

```
class Base
{
public:
  void foo() {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  using Base::foo;
  void foo() & {}
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;

  // Clang says here: error: call to member function 'foo' is ambiguous. Gcc,
  // however, is fine with it
  d.foo();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is overloading on just one ref-qualifier not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389911/why-is-overloading-on-just-one-ref-qualifier-not-allowed)

Comment: @kotatsuyaki There's no overloading here, so I don't think so. Here the new declaration of `foo` is either supposed to shadow the old one, or not

Comment: I have found another duplicate that's closer to this question: [Overloading a parent member function without ref-qualifier with a child member function with ref-qualifier in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70015603/12122460)

Comment: Appears so, yes, but it unfortunately doesn't answer my main question - which compiler is actually wrong, and I'd rather report the bug